# Entity can find object but it can't delete it

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Entity can find object and can set the properties of it but it throws "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager." exception when I try to delete it. 
You can see my story in belong pics.

As you can see, object is not null and entity can find it.

[image]

I can see the object whicgh I want to delete in context.

[image]

Do you have any suggestion about it?

Thanks,

Comment: How are you retrieving the entity from the database? It seems that the entity is not being tracked. Are you using `AsNoTracking()` method?

Comment: I use this code for retrieving :   using (var context = new eTicaretEntity())
                {
                    return context.carts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CartGuid == cartGuid && x.ProductId == productId && x.ProductTypeId == productTypeId);
                }

Comment: You need to use the same context to delete the entity, so the context can track it. Try putting the code that deletes the entity inside the using statement

Comment: It will be easier for us to help you if you edit your answer and include some source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are disposing the context right after getting the entity. This way Entity Framework cannot keep track of the changes mad to that entity.
Try putting the delete code inside the using statement:

```
using (var context = new eTicaretEntity()) 
{ 
    var cart = context.carts.FirstOrDefault(x => 
        x.CartGuid == cartGuid && 
        x.ProductId == productId 
        && x.ProductTypeId == productTypeId); 

    // delete entity here
    // .....
}
```